# VHDL - eight-LED sequential control circuit

Tags: vhdl, fpga, quartus, ieee

I am quite new with FPGA and i would like some help if that is possible.
 
I would like to implement an eight-LED sequential control circuit with Quartus.
 It is going to be externally controlled by me via the GPIOs The GPIO[1] for example will be the reset and the GPIO[0] will be the signal.
When i change the GPIO [0] signal (from '0' to '1' and vice versa), the circuit will have to switch to the next among three states, defined as follows:

A) The **LED [0: 1]** periodically flashes with a period of **2 seconds** (stays on for 1 sec) while **LED [3: 7]** remains off.

B) **LED [3: 4]** flashes periodically for **6 sec** (remain on for 3 sec) while **LED [0: 2]** and **[5: 7]** remain off.

C) **LED [6: 7]** flashes periodically with a period of **12 seconds** (stays on for 6 sec), while **LED [0: 5]** remains off.

So i wrote this VHDL code.

```
library IEEE;
   use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
   USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all ;
   USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all ;

library altera_mf;
use altera_mf.altera_mf_components.all;
entity exone is
  --//=======================================================
  --//  PORT declarations
  --//=======================================================
  PORT (
  --    //////////// CLOCK //////////
      CLOCK_50         : IN STD_LOGIC;
      LED            :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
      GPIO_2        : INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0)
  );
end exone ;

architecture rtl of exone is

signal led_s : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0 );
signal inp : STD_LOGIC ;
signal state : integer := 3 ;
signal rst, clk : STD_LOGIC ;
signal cnt1: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 19 downto 0);
signal cnt2: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 19 downto 0);

begin
clk <= CLOCK_50 ;
inp <= GPIO_2(0);
rst <= GPIO_2(1);

process (clk, rst, inp) -- CYCLE
begin
    if rst='1' then
              cnt1<=(others=>'0');
              cnt2<=(others=>'0');
              led_s<=(others=>'0');
       elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then
         cnt1 <= cnt1 + 1;
          if (cnt1=1000000) then
              cnt2 <= cnt2+1;
              cnt1 <= (others=>'0');
          end if;

  if inp = '1' and state = 3 then
    state <= 1 ;
    if (cnt2=0) then
      led_s <= "11000000";
    elsif (cnt2=50) then
      led_s <= "00000000";
    elsif (cnt2=100) then
      cnt2<=(others=>'0');
    else
      led_s <= led_s;
    end if ;

  elsif inp = '0' then
      if (cnt2=0) then
        led_s <= "00011000";
      elsif (cnt2=150) then
        led_s <= "00000000";
      elsif (cnt2=300) then
        cnt2<=(others=>'0');
      else
        led_s <= led_s;
      end if;

  else
    state <= 3 ;
    if (cnt2=0) then
      led_s <= "00000011";
    elsif (cnt2=300) then
      led_s <= "00000000";
    elsif (cnt2=600) then
      cnt2<=(others=>'0');
    else
      led_s <= led_s;
    end if ;

end if;
  end if;
end process ;
  LED <= led_s ;
END rtl ;
```

This is the simplest solution that i could imagine. The thing is that the part

```
if inp = '1' and state = 3 then
    state <= 1 ;
    if (cnt2=0) then
      led_s <= "11000000";
    elsif (cnt2=50) then
      led_s <= "00000000";
    elsif (cnt2=100) then
      cnt2<=(others=>'0');
    else
      led_s <= led_s;
    end if ;

  elsif inp = '0' then
      if (cnt2=0) then
        led_s <= "00011000";
      elsif (cnt2=150) then
        led_s <= "00000000";
      elsif (cnt2=300) then
        cnt2<=(others=>'0');
      else
        led_s <= led_s;
      end if;

  else
    state <= 3 ;
    if (cnt2=0) then
      led_s <= "00000011";
    elsif (cnt2=300) then
      led_s <= "00000000";
    elsif (cnt2=600) then
      cnt2<=(others=>'0');
    else
      led_s <= led_s;
    end if ;
```

Does not seem to work so good. I have been trying to find what is wrong for many hours, but still no luck.
 
So my question is: 
Is there any better ways to check for **inp** changes and also flag the states ? 
 
I believe that the code that i wrote is garbage and too big for what i want to achieve.

Comment: *" I have been trying to find what is wrong for many hours"* Did you write a test-bench and looked at the resulting waveforms?

Comment: I am working on that now. But i cant figure it out.